# The injection is not working in angular application

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have an Angular application nested in the MVC application. I'm trying to extract it and have it as a stand-alone application.

I created a new angular application, minimal version using CLI, copied my package.json, installed all packages, added a few components from the existing application, it builds and serves but when I try to run it I get an injection-related error.

Here are samples of my code `package.json`, `app.module.ts`, `app.config.ts`, `privacy.component.ts`, `app-routing.module.ts`

package.json

```
{
  "name": "myApplication",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
    "@alyle/ui": "^1.9.9",
    "@angular/animations": "^7.1.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.3.7",
    "@angular/common": "~7.1.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.1.4",
    "@angular/core": "^7.1.4",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.1.4",
    "@angular/http": "~7.1.4",
    "@angular/material": "^7.2.0",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.1.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.1.4",
    "@angular/router": "~7.1.4",
    "@ngrx/router-store": "^8.1.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^8.1.0",
    "angular-gauge": "^3.1.1",
    "angular2-resizing-cropping-image": "^1.0.0",
    "chroma-js": "^2.0.2",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^2.6.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery-validation": "^1.19.0",
    "moment": "^2.23.0",
    "ngx-bar-rating": "^1.1.0",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^2.1.0",
    "ngx-google-places-autocomplete": "^2.0.4",
    "oidc-client": "^1.8.2",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.2",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.11.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.1.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.1.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.4",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.6",
    "@types/node": "~10.12.18",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.3.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.1.4",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.4",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.1",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.1",
    "tslint": "^5.12.0",
    "typescript": "~3.4.3"
  }
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule, Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { MaterialModule } from './material.module';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { PrivacyComponent } from "./shared/privacy/privacy.component";
import { AppConfig } from './app.config';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,

    PrivacyComponent        
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MaterialModule
  ],
  providers: [AppConfig],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.config.ts

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AppConfig {

    constructor() {}

    siteName: string = "Site Name";
    siteUrl: string = "siteurl.com";
}
```

privacy.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AppConfig } from '../../app.config';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-privacy',
    templateUrl: './privacy.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./privacy.component.css']
})
export class PrivacyComponent implements OnInit {

    siteName: string = this.config.siteName;
    siteUrl: string = this.config.siteUrl;

    constructor(private config: AppConfig
        ) { }

    ngOnInit() {

    }
}
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { PrivacyComponent } from "./shared/privacy/privacy.component";

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "", component: PrivacyComponent},
  { path: "privacy", component: PrivacyComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

When I try to access the page I'm getting the

```
compiler.js:2193 Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for PrivacyComponent: (?).
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:2193)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (compiler.js:17643)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata (compiler.js:17539)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNonNormalizedDirectiveMetadata (compiler.js:17168)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getEntryComponentMetadata (compiler.js:17738)
    at compiler.js:17730
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getEntryComponentsFromProvider (compiler.js:17729)
    at compiler.js:17700
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
syntaxError @ compiler.js:2193
_getDependenciesMetadata @ compiler.js:17643
_getTypeMetadata @ compiler.js:17539
getNonNormalizedDirectiveMetadata @ compiler.js:17168
_getEntryComponentMetadata @ compiler.js:17738
(anonymous) @ compiler.js:17730
_getEntryComponentsFromProvider @ compiler.js:17729
(anonymous) @ compiler.js:17700
_getProvidersMetadata @ compiler.js:17663
(anonymous) @ compiler.js:17665
_getProvidersMetadata @ compiler.js:17663
(anonymous) @ compiler.js:17295
getNgModuleMetadata @ compiler.js:17286
getNgModuleSummary @ compiler.js:17226
(anonymous) @ compiler.js:17308
getNgModuleMetadata @ compiler.js:17286
_loadModules @ compiler.js:24229
_compileModuleAndComponents @ compiler.js:24212
compileModuleAsync @ compiler.js:24174
compileModuleAsync @ platform-browser-dynamic.js:214
compileNgModuleFactory__PRE_R3__ @ core.js:20711
bootstrapModule @ core.js:20935
./src/main.ts @ main.ts:11
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:78
0 @ main.ts:12
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:78
checkDeferredModules @ bootstrap:45
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap:32
(anonymous) @ main.js:1
```

which looks like related to the `AppConfig` that I'm trying to inject. Not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: You're providing AppConfig two times. `@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})` and `providers: [AppConfig],`

Answer (score 1):

I see a mistake here, you're trying to access `this.config` before injecting service in to constructor.

```
export class PrivacyComponent implements OnInit {
    // First declare variables
    siteName: string ;
    siteUrl: string ;
    constructor(private config: AppConfig) {
     // And then assign values here

    siteName = this.config.siteName;
    siteUrl = this.config.siteUrl;
 }

    ngOnInit() {

    }
}
```

And usually you should name service accordingly `ConfigurationService` and then inject in constuctor with same name but with first letter in lower case

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})

export class ConfigurationService {
  serverUrl = 'https://my-website.com';
  siteName = 'Your site'

  constructor() {} 
}

// And here is component where do you need ConfigurationService

export class MyComponent{
  serverUrl;
  siteName;

  constructor(private configurationService: ConfigurationService  ) {
     this.serverUrl = this.configurationService.serverUrl;
     this.siteName = this.configurationService.siteName;
  } 
}
```

Comment: sorry it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: It should work, show again error code or put code in codepen with fixed code what I've wrote above

Comment: Add to your imports array these two modulese : `CommonModule, RouterModule`, because you're trying to use router link but you haven't imported RouterModule from angular to enable routes, and also make sure to have imported and CommonModule

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [**ritaj**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7436489/ritaj), if you've `providedIn: 'root'`, the service would be provided on the Root Injector. In that case, you don't have to provide the service explicitly by adding it to the `providers` array.

It generally works just fine. But just to be on the safe side, get rid of that, and your app should work just fine:

```
import { BrowserModule, Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { MaterialModule } from './material.module';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { PrivacyComponent } from "./shared/privacy/privacy.component";
import { AppConfig } from './app.config';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,

    PrivacyComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MaterialModule
  ],
  // providers: [AppConfig],  // COMMENT THIS LINE
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-app-service-provided-in-root?file=src/app/app.module.ts) for your ref.

Comment: I tried with and without it specifying it in the providers section. I removed it and still throws exactly the same error.

Comment: I added the complete error in the post. here is just a header compiler.js:2193 Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for PrivacyComponent: (?).
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:2193)

Comment: Try adding `PrivacyComponent ` to the `entryComponents` array in your `AppModule`'s `@NgModule` decorator. Check my sample Stackblitz for the same.

Comment: i have it in the declarations section. I suspect the error may be related to the package.json and components I have there. Interesting everything works fine in the existing application

Comment: @siddahmera btw the examle on stackblitz doesn't render privacy component content

Comment: How about now? I also think that you've created a `SharedModule` that encapsulates the `PrivacyComponent`. If that's indeed the case, then you might want to add the `SharedModule` to the `imports` array fo the `AppModule` and add the `PrivacyComponent` to the `declarations` and `exports` arrays of the `SharedModule`